# AttributeError: type object has no attribute (problem with *args?)

Tags: python, attributeerror

Note: This is not a duplicate of [AttributeError: type object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546940/attributeerror-type-object-has-no-attribute).
I am trying to code a text-adventure.

```
class place(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(place, self).__init__()
        self.directions = {
            "N":None,
            "S":None,
            "E":None,
            "W":None,
            "NE":None,
            "NW":None,
            "SE":None,
            "SW":None
        }


    def add_directions(self, *args): #There's a problem with putting *args because it takes self as string
        #I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this
        for direction in args:
            for key in self.directions:
                self.directions[key] = direction
        print(self)

place()
place.add_directions(place, "The Dark Room")
```

I wish to add "The Dark Room" to the class variable "self.directions". However, whenever I do so, they give this error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" "C:/Users/samue/Documents/School/Y3 2020/Computer Science/Python/TextAdventure/The Dark Asylum.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/samue/Documents/School/Y3 2020/Computer Science/Python/TextAdventure/The Dark Asylum.py", line 25, in <module>
    place.add_directions(place, "No")
  File "C:/Users/samue/Documents/School/Y3 2020/Computer Science/Python/TextAdventure/The Dark Asylum.py", line 20, in add_directions
    for key in self.directions:
AttributeError: type object 'place' has no attribute 'directions'
```

I know my understanding of objects are not that good, but could someone help me to assign individual directions, in **string** to each key in the class variable `self.directions`? Is it something wrong with `*args` in the function `add_directions`?

Comment: As an aside, this looks like python 2. Are you using python 3? Then `class place:` and `super().__init__()` are the way to go. And you don't need to call `__init__` when you are just inheriting from the base Object.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm using python 3. Thanks for the advice, I just started learning OOP.

Comment: It can be a challenge because you can come across python 2 examples and tutorials and not know you are doing it the old way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`place.add_directions(place, "The Dark Room")`

In this line, you are referencing the class place and not an instance of the place class,

In python and other Object oriented programming languages, you first need to instantiate or initialize a class before accessing its members.

```
place_instance = place()
place_instance.add_directions("The Dark Room")
```

It is not necessary to pass the class as `self` as you have done, `self` is need to define methods, not when calling methods.

To make this code more readable, consider using an uppercase letter for place. It could be written as `class Place()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Really appreciate it

Comment: you're welcome and all the best :) This game sounds fun to play :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign `place()` to a variable (making it an instance), before using that variable (as an instance). That's why all of the answers are:

```
instance = place() 
instance.add_directions("The Dark Room")
```

I hope this will clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your last 2 lines:

```
place()
place.add_directions(place, "The Dark Room")
```

Should be:

```
p = place()
p.add_directions("The Dark Room")
```

You were calling the `place` constructor, but not assigning it anywhere.  You don't need to pass `place` for `self`, the `p` part in `p.add_directions` is automatically `self`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create instance of the class place. place() - is instance of the class place, place - class itself. Also you do not need to pass argument for self. It will be passed automatically. You code should be

```
p = place()
p.add_directions("The Dark Room")
```

P.S.By convention you should uppercase first letter of the class